# Convergence or divergence of infinite power towers of complex numbers $z^{z^{z^{z{...}}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, tetration, lambert-w

Let $s$ be any complex number, $t = e^s$ and $z = t^{1/t}$.  Define the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ by $a_0 = z $ and $a_{n+1} = z^{a_n} $ for $n \geq 0$, that is to say $a_n$ is the sequence $z$, $z^z$, $z^{z^z}$, $z^{z^{z^{z}}}$ and so on.

I want to show that the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $t$ *if and only if* $s$ lies in the unit disk.  I know that when the sequence converges the limit is $\frac{W(-\ln(z))}{-\ln(z)}$ where $W$ is the Lambert W function.

I have verified the above statements numerically for several thousand values of $z$ but I have no idea how to actually prove it.

I graphed the natural logs of the limits on my computer. I got what appeared to be the unit disk.

If we take the log of the limit we get $\ln\left(\frac{W(−\ln(z)}{−\ln(z)}\right)=-\ln(−\ln(z))−W(−\ln(z))+\ln(−\ln(z))=−W(−\ln(z))$

So what I want to prove is equivalent to showing the sequence $a_n$ is convergent if and only if $|W(−\ln(z))| \leq 1$

I was reading the Wikipedia article on the Lambert W Function and I found this proof that the limit $c$, when it exists, is $c= \frac{W(-\ln(z))}{-\ln(z)}$

$z^c = c\implies z = c^{1/c} \implies z^{-1} = c^{-1/c} \implies 1/z = (1/c)^{1/c} \implies -\ln(z) = \frac{\ln(1/c)}{c} \implies -\ln(z) = e^{\ln(1/c)}\ln(1/c) \implies \ln(1/c) = W(-\ln(z)) \implies 1/c = e^{W(-\ln(z))} \implies \frac{1}{c} = \frac{-\ln(z)}{W(-\ln(z)} \implies c = \frac{W(-\ln(z)}{-\ln(z)}$

I can only assume that at least 1 step is not justified when $|W(-\ln(z)| > 1$ though I am not sure which one.  I think that part of the problem is the equation $z^c=c$ has a solution for every non-zero complex number $c$ while the sequence $a_n$ only converges for certain special values of z.  In other words the convergence of the $a_n$ is a sufficient but not necessary condition for the existence of a solution to the equation.

Comment: @Did Here $w$ is the Lambert W function; it is not an undefined variable.

Comment: What is $u^z$ when $u$ and $z$ are complex numbers?

Comment: @Did In polar coordinates $(re^{iu})^(se^{iv}) = (re^{iu})^s*(re^{iu}))^(e^{iv}) = ?$

Comment: @Did In polar coordinates $(re^{iu})^(se^{iv}) = (re^{iu})^s*(re^{iu}))^(e^{iv}) = r^{s}e^{ius}r^{e^{iu}}e^{-uv} = r^{s+iu}e^{ius-uv}=?$

Comment: Why does everyone seem to answer questions in the comments?

Comment: Except that, unless $z$ is an integer, this leads to possibly infinitely many values for $u^z$... For example, $u=1$ and $z=\sqrt2$ would yield that $u^z$ is $\exp(2i\pi n\sqrt2)$ for every integer $n$, which is a dense set of points on the unit circle. This example indicates the question is in serious need of explanations.

Comment: I suppose I should point that I am defining all of the expressions using the principal branch of the natural log

Comment: This is another problem for another day, but I am attempting to extend my results so that they are valid for any branch of the natural log.  My progress on this has been very slow.

Comment: @Did You are correct in that the expression $u^z$ is multivalued, since the complex logarithm is multivalued.  Please note however that I am restricting my attention to the principal branch of the log so that all expressions are single-valued.  Note also that in the original post, only $s$ is arbitrary; $t$, $z$ and the sequence $a_n$ are all defined in terms of $s$.

Comment: Maybe start with complex number $a$ (to be thought of as $\log z$), then iterate using function  $t \mapsto \exp(at)$ instead of  function $x \mapsto z^x$.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if my question is even answerable

Comment: I tried, unsuccessfully, sorry.

Comment: @Næreen What was your idea?

Comment: If anybody has any idea at all please say it.  I am wide open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_0 = z\qquad \qquad \qquad a_{n+1} = z^{a_n}$$

let $b_n = \ln a_n$ so $a_n = e^{b_n}$ and $$b_{n+1} =  \ln \left(z^{e^{b_n}}\right) = e^{b_n} \ln z$$

if $b_n$ converges to $b$ then $b = e^b \ln z = - e^{b} (-\ln z)$ so

$$b = e^b \ln z =  W(-\ln z)$$

where $W$ is (**one of the branches of** ?) the [Lambert function](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_W_de_Lambert#Comme_limite_d.27une_suite).

let $c_n = b_n - b$ so $$c_{n+1} = e^{(b + c_n)} \ln z - b= (e^b \ln z) e^{c_n}  - b  = b e^{c_n}  - b = b (e^{c_n}  - 1)$$

> suppose $|b| > 1$ and $\ln z \ne 0$. then suppose $b_n \to b$ thus $c_n \to 0$  so $e^{c_n}-1 \sim c_n$ so $c_{n+1} \sim b c_n  $ which clearly cannot converge except if $c_0 = 0$ which would imply $c_n = 0$ for every $n$ which is not the case because $b_0 = \ln z$ so $b_1 = e^{\ln z} \ln z \ne b_0$ so $c_1 \ne c_0$ $\implies$ a contradiction.

hence if $\ln z \ne 0$ $$|b| = \left|W(-\ln z)\right| \le 1$$ is a necessary condition for the convergence of $(b_n)$ and $(a_n)$

Comment: Can you show that $|b| \leq 1$ is also a sufficient condition for the convergence of the sequences?

Comment: Also, a few some minor points: first $b = ln(a)$ is actually equal to $-W(-ln(z))$.  Second I believe it is not necessary to assume $ln(z) \ne 0$ or $z \ne 1$; $W(0)$ is perfectly well defined since $0*e^0 =0$ and $0 \leq 1$.  Looks good otherwise.

Comment: Can you show that $|b| \leq 1$ is also a sufficient condition for the convergence of the sequences?

Comment: @cpiegore : as I shown it reduces to solving the convergence of $c_{n+1} = b(e^{c_n}-1)$ which is easy in $\mathbb{R}$ but much less in $\mathbb{C}$. it is probably already solved somewhere so make a research. and you'll probably have to show by induction that $Re(c_n)$ and $|c_n|$ let $c_n$ converge, maybe by studying $arg(c_n)$ ? you could also simulate the sequence on a computer to see what is happening when it converges or diverges (and I don't think it converges for most $|b| = 1$).

Answer (score 0):

I was reading the Wikipedia article on the Lambert W Function and I found this proof that the limit $c$, when it exists, is $c= \frac{w(-ln(z))}{-ln(z)}$

$z^c = c\implies z = c^{1/c} \implies z^{-1} = c^{-1/c} \implies 1/z = (1/c)^{1/c} \implies -ln(z) = \frac{ln(1/c)}{c} \implies -ln(z) = e^{ln(1/c)}ln(1/c) \implies ln(1/c) = W(-ln(z)) \implies 1/c = e^{W(-ln(z))} \implies \frac{1}{c} = \frac{-ln(z)}{W(-ln(z)} \implies c = \frac{W(-ln(z)}{-ln(z)}$

I can only assume that at least 1 step is not justified when $|W(-ln(z)| > 1$ though I am not sure which one.