# If $|t| = |W(-\ln z)| = 1$ and $t^n =1$ then $z^{z^{z^{...}}}$ is convergent

Tags: reference-request, lambert-w, tetration

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $W$ be the Lambert W function.  In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757474/convergence-properties-of-zzz-and-is-it-chaotic) post I was told if $|t| = |W(-\ln z)| = 1$ and $t^n =1$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ than the iterated exponential $z^{z^{z^{...}}}$ is convergent, and that this is proved by Baker and Rippon.  However, I have found that the relevant article is not freely available.

I am asking for a link to an article, possibly by a different author, which proves this or an equivalent statement.  Preferably, the article should be freely available, no questions asked.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you very much.  I have been trying to get my hands on that article for several days.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Why do you want to remove the link?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Anyways yes I did save my personal copy.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Then go ahead and remove it; I have my copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make it possible to "close the case":
The article is possibly

Baker, I. N., and Rippon P. J. "A Note on Complex Iteration." The American Mathematical Monthly 92.7 (1985): 501-04. Web.

This is online, for instance via [JStor](http://www.jstor.org). (Access possible using an account of an affiliated university or organiszation)